# jQuery Mobile and Google Graph API

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am trying to set Google Chart using API generated from below link

[Google Charts](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#line_chart)

The problem is now that it is not working with jQuery Mobile and I'm getting `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` error

The code is exactly same as what was generated and it's inside the div of data-role=page

What seems to be the problem?

UPDATE:

Sorry guys the code is here...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});
    </script>

$('#suburb-stats').live('pageinit', function(){
        function drawVisualization() {
          // Create and populate the data table.
          var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
          data.addColumn('string', 'x');
          data.addColumn('number', 'Cats');
          data.addColumn('number', 'Blanket 1');
          data.addColumn('number', 'Blanket 2');
          data.addRow(["A", 1, 1, 0.5]);
          data.addRow(["B", 2, 0.5, 1]);
          data.addRow(["C", 4, 1, 0.5]);
          data.addRow(["D", 8, 0.5, 1]);
          data.addRow(["E", 7, 1, 0.5]);
          data.addRow(["F", 7, 0.5, 1]);
          data.addRow(["G", 8, 1, 0.5]);
          data.addRow(["H", 4, 0.5, 1]);
          data.addRow(["I", 2, 1, 0.5]);
          data.addRow(["J", 3.5, 0.5, 1]);
          data.addRow(["K", 3, 1, 0.5]);
          data.addRow(["L", 3.5, 0.5, 1]);
          data.addRow(["M", 1, 1, 0.5]);
          data.addRow(["N", 1, 0.5, 1]);

          // Create and draw the visualization.
          new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
              draw(data, {curveType: "function",
                          width: 500, height: 400,
                          vAxis: {maxValue: 10}, legend: {position: 'bottom'},
                          pointSize: 5
                          }
                  );
        }
        ​google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
    });

<div id="visualization" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>
```

Comment: who knows, you didn't post any code...

Comment: Please post the relevant code snippet so we can help with your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least based on what you posted, most of your JavaScript code is *outside* of the script tags.

Comment: Sorry it is actually inside script tags

Comment: Your script tags are not nested inside other script tags are they?